# Integrate Android's Connection (from ConnectionService) with OpenTok Audio stream

Tags: android, voip, opentok

We have an Android application which implements a `SelfManaged` `ConnectionService` to interact with the built-in telephony. We use OpenTok as the VOIP provider.

So far, when we receive a call, we call `telecomManager.AddNewIncomingCall()` to alert the system for an incoming call, and then on `onShowIncomingCallUI()` we display the notification.
When our user accept the call, we call `SetActive()` on the current `Connection` and start the call.

We experience a problem with the above setup, which is that our user cannot hear the other side. Video is OK and the other side does hear us.

After debugging the issue we came to a temporary solution which is to not call `SetActive()` on the `Connection`, but rather call `SetDisconnected()` and `Destroy()`.
We suspect that the active `Connection` gets a higher audio focus from the OS, which explains why we cannot hear while the `Connection` is active and not destroyed.

How can we still keep the `Connection` active while the call is active, and use the `Connection`'s audio focus that it receives from the OS?

We have tried calling `audioManager.RequestAudioFocus` with `GAIN` or `GAIN_TRANSIENT` with no success so far.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a small project that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @AlanThomson No, we ended up ditching `TelecomManager` and implemented it normally (per OpenTok documentation).